# How to run offline "Progressive Web Apps"?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I am new in progressive Webs Apps development. I want to implement progressive webs app. So I have implemented one demo page and this page working fine with net connection but without network(In Offline) it is not working.

I want to open my progressive website without any internet connection(offline). I have seen one link https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/offline/. And I have implemented service worker javascript file.

[image]

**I will explain step by step:**

**First Step**:

I am using *web server chrome:*
[image]

**Second Step:**
index.html

```
  // Register the service worker if available.
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('./service-worker.js').then(function(reg) {
  console.log('Successfully registered service worker', reg);
  }).catch(function(err) {
  console.warn('Error whilst registering service worker', err);
  });
  }

  window.addEventListener('online', function(e) {
  // Resync data with server.
  console.log("You are online");
  Page.hideOfflineWarning();
  Arrivals.loadData();
  }, false);

  window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) {
  // Queue up events for server.
  console.log("You are offline");
  Page.showOfflineWarning();
  }, false);

  // Check if the user is connected.
  if (navigator.onLine) {
  Arrivals.loadData();
  } else {
  // Show offline message
  Page.showOfflineWarning();
  }

  // Set Knockout view model bindings.
  ko.applyBindings(Page.vm);
```

**Service-worker.js**

```
// Use a cacheName for cache versioning
  var cacheName = 'v1:static';

  // During the installation phase, you'll usually want to cache static assets.
  self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  // Once the service worker is installed, go ahead and fetch the resources to make this work offline.
  e.waitUntil(
  caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
  return cache.addAll([
  './index.html',
  './screen.css',
  './script.js',
  './styles/app.css',
  './styles/font.css',
  './styles/header.css',
  './styles/hidden.css',
  './styles/list.css',
  './styles/page.css',
  './styles/suggest.css',
  './styles/tags.css', 

  ]).then(function() {
  self.skipWaiting();
  });
  })
  );
  });

  // when the browser fetches a URL…
  self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  // … either respond with the cached object or go ahead and fetch the actual URL
  event.respondWith(
  caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
  if (response) {
  // retrieve from cache
  return response;
  }
  // fetch as normal
  return fetch(event.request);
  })
  );
  });
```

**Third Step**
Check in Network:
[image]

**Check in Application:**
Service-worker.js file working fine you can see in screen shot:
[image]

But when I clicked on offline check box my website is not working. If all these things did right way then its have to open in offline.
[image]

If anything missing then please let me know. Please don't decline this question. If anybody has an idea then please share.

> If anybody has doubt then see this link https://pwa.rocks/. You can
>   open this link in chrome and after then without internet connection it
>   will open.

If explanation need then please ask from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra condition for the root request `/` when handling the `fetch` event:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    // … either respond with the cached object or go ahead and fetch the actual URL
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            if (response) {
                // retrieve from cache
                return response;
            }

            // if not found in cache, return default offline content (only if this is a navigation request)
            if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
                return caches.match('./index.html');
            }

            // fetch as normal
            return fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's your code from service-worker.js. I just added the condition for `event.request.mode === 'navigate' - it's for the initial request.

Comment: I'm also experimenting with Progressive Web Apps recently. I've built 2 simple PWAs with [UpUp](https://github.com/TalAter/UpUp/) - a library that simplifies implemention of PWAs. You can find my source code here https://github.com/toolity/toolity.github.io

Comment: The cleaner option would probably be to change `'./index.html'` in the `cacheAll` to just be `'./'`

Comment: Which UI framework is good for the Progressive web apps.(Like Bootstrap, Materialize, and any other?)